# Git > Oozie source code

Tags: git, tree, git-branch

I am reading the Oozie source code in GIT currently, and found something odd:

There are two different releases:

- https://github.com/mapr/oozie/tree/4.2.0-mapr-1601
- https://github.com/mapr/oozie/tree/4.2.0-mapr-1510

But in these two different pages, the given git link are both: git@github.com:mapr/oozie.git

So if I use the given link to clone the project to my local PC, it is totally the same code. But how come there are two different versions/trees? Then when I turn to different branches, the link of the branch is also in the format https://github.com/mapr/oozie/tree/[BRANCH]

Why is it like this?

Answer (score 0):

The link `git@github.com:mapr/oozie.git` is the link to the repo as a whole. You have access to the entire repository, and it's on you as the user to determine what in the repo you want to checkout.